# One If Then, Multiple FOR Loops VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, with-statement

In short, I am trying to copy two different selections and paste them in two different locations in two different sheets. The amount of cells the selections are pasted into are dictated by a drop down on one of the sheets. One selection has data, the other formatting. The first With statement and FOR Loop work great. Nothing happens on the With/FOR for the second sheet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Sheets("INPUT").Range("A2")
Dim nextrow As Long, i As Long

   If KeyCells < 8 Then
        With Sheets("SIG")
            .Range("SigLines").Copy
            For i = 1 To KeyCells - 1
                nextrow = .Cells(Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("SIG").Range("H" & nextrow + 2).PasteSpecial
            Next i
        End With
        With Sheets("INPUT")
            .Range("BorrowerNameList").Copy
            For i = 1 To KeyCells - 1
                nextrow = .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("INPUT").Range("C" & nextrow + 2).PasteSpecial xlsFormats
            Next i
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: *nothing happens*... Have you tried stepping through your code using F8 in debug mode?

Comment: Also worth noting, you've pasted *only* the *Formats* on the second loop. Since I can't see your workbook, I can't tell whether there are any formats that would be visible. If there are no formats applied to either source or destination range, then there won't be any visible changes to the destination range.

Comment: The first loop is just for values. The second loop is for formatting in cells.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up with was creating a Worksheet_SelectionChange for one sheet that handles its changes but also calls a macro workbook level to handle the changes on the other sheet.